# Как решить математическое выражение на C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

я не знаю как это сделать, подскажите как это сделать. Я знаю что в js есть команда `eval()`
которая все решит. В **C++/CLI** как быть? Мне Lua не надо, только на **C++/CLI**.

```cpp
this->InputTextBox->Text
```

Хочу взять с this->InputTextBox->Text строку и превратить его в тип string:

```cpp
String^ Matematic = gcnew String(InputTextBox->Text);
```

после этого мне надо его превратить в тип int, как это сделать? Я не знаю.
потом решить математическое выражение или пример и сделать так что то типа:

```cpp
this->InputTextBox->Text = result;
```

P.S (Было бы клево если на **C++** `eval()` был как в **Js** ).

Comment: Смысл подобных заданий как раз и состоит в написании собственного упрощенного аналога eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел на английском stackoverflow ответ только на **С#**. Имеет такой вид:

```cs
string mystring = "3*(2+4)";
int result = EvaluateExpression(mystring);
Console.Writeln(result); // Outputs 18
```

Сделал на **C++/CLI** вот таким образом:

```cpp
String^ CalcMatematic = InputTextBox->Text; // Берем текст с TextBox
Data::DataTable ^dt = gcnew DataTable();
auto res = dt->Compute(CalcMatematic, "");
this->InputTextBox->Text = res->ToString(); // в TextBox вносим результат.
```

P.S(Надеюсь кому то помог );

Answer (score 2):

Надо начать с того, что `eval()` - это довольно небезопасная операция в JS. Можно начать с того, что если не проверить выражение, то можно внести в текстбокс вместо выражения текст программы, котрый модифицирует ту самую страницу, на которой вызывается eval().

Теперь о C++.

Еще раз повторю, проблема в том, что не все выражения - высчислимые. Например, могут быть выражения с нарушенным балансом скобок.

Кроме того, если что то типа

```
     (1+4*25)*(6-14+2+30) - 65 +2*3
```

вычисляются, и всем более-менее понятно, что должно получиться в результате, то как высчислить

```
    (2*a+1)(3*b-2)
```

Что в этом случае является ответом?

И как ограничены выражения - полиномами?

амая сложная часть задачи - это определение того, что выражение - правильное.

в общем случае понадобится либо построение AST, либо хотя бы проверка соответствия БНФ'у

Правда, если задача ограниченная - как в первом примере - то она решается наэлементарном уровне:

1. проверяем баланс скобок
2. начинаем вычислять при помощи стековой машины, учитывая приоритет операций. Это описано "алгоритмом сортировщика" еще у Дэйкстры.

в концк вычисления на вершине стека будет ответ.

Я не приводил ссылок, но по кллючевым словам Вы легко найдете все, что нужно.